# Difference between the ordinary and extraordinary wind in Talmud

Tags: talmud-gemara, sukkah, sukkot

There are several instances that recur to the distinction between ordinary and extraordinary. For example  wind. For instance:

Sukkah must withstand *ordinary wind* (Orach Chayim 630.10)

When one wind is considered ordinary and when extraordinary wind? There's a distinction, but not definition, in [Bava Kama 45](http://dafyomi.co.il/bkama/insites/bk-dt-045.htm):

- The prevailing wind is: *ru'ach Metzuyah*.
- The unusual strong wind is *ru'ach she'Eino Metzuyah*.

Is there something that marks a difference between them? how to decide whether it is one or the other?

**EDIT**:
Possible criteria to evaluate between prevailing and unusual wind were:

1. Succah construction dictates unusual wind: local experience may have led to improve the construction of succah to resist the prevailing high winds. So, a wind that damaged the succah built according to the common practice was a unusual wind.
2. The local elderly or writings dictates unusual wind: what the older people of the community remembered, or a written historical record, was an unusual wind.

thanks!

Comment: It means your sukkah doesn't have to be so strong it can withstand a hurricane.

Comment: Right, but I'm wondering if there's any reference that deals more in detail with a definition of when one wind is considered ordinary and when extraordinary wind?

Comment: Is there a way to gauge that? I think it's more like when you look outside and see the leaves rustling in the trees to looking outside and seeing the trees bending.

Comment: Not really. I'm asking about a distinction. I added more details to question

Comment: I'm quite certain that there's a M.Y. question that addresses the main part of your question. I have to hunt for it. But, I recall that the term ru'ach Metzuyah is exactly according to your translation, i.e. "prevailing wind", meaning what the most common wind speed is in your area. If you live at the top of Mt. Washington, VT, the prevailing wind speed there is about 40 - 50 MPH. If you live in New York City, the prevailing wind is around 10 - 15 MPH. If you're uncertain what it is in your area, you can always contact a local meteorologist or in the U.S. view www.weather.gov.

Comment: I really don't see how your question here is different from the one Yishai voted for, some I'm voting to close based on the same possible dupe. If you can edit this question  further, I'll consider retracting the vote.

Comment: I believe it's different because it requires more information about the decision. Your answer is focused only on the locality aspect of normal. I edited my question